# Group records conditionally in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I've a file which has 2 columns as Column1 and Column2 and holding records as below -

[File in HDFS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1eRN.jpg)

Record 1 A is the main record and record 2 Column2 holds the information linked with A, Similarly the information with B C and D respectively. What I am looking for is to club these information and gets the following desired output.

[Desired output look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHlqS.jpg)
I can't do any modifications in the HDFS file, anything and everything in hadoop environment only.
How this can be achieved? Any help!!

Answer (score 0):

After loading the data,

```
A = load '' as col1,col2;

B =  FOREACH A GENERATE (col1 is null?substr(col2,1):col1),col2;
```